# abnormal behavior javascript select alert

Tags: javascript

as the title a working script behaves me abnormally, specifically the script is this, nothing complicated. When you do not select a field, you can issue an alert with a custom phrase.

html:

```
<form onSubmit="return FORM_A();">
<select id="FIRST_ID" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
 <select id="SECOND_ID" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />  
</form>
```

js:

```
function FORM_A(){
    var EXAMPLE_ONE=document.getElementById("FIRST_ID").value;//alert(e);
    if(EXAMPLE_ONE===""){
        alert("Nothing Select in first select");
        return false;
    }
        var EXAMPLE_TWO=document.getElementById("SECOND_ID").value;//alert(e);
    if(EXAMPLE_TWO===""){
        alert("Nothing Select in second select");
        return false;
    }
}
```

as mentioned before, a very simple example.

My problem is when I report the same example on my code, I get an alert for the first select correct, but when I select a value in the first select and I miss selecting the second and I do not select anything in the second select, I always leave the alert of the first select, unless I delete this piece of code:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Nominativo cliente</option>
```

Complete Code:

```
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <form onSubmit="return SELEZIONA_FORM();" method="post" action="associa.php" class="text-center border border-light p-5">
            <p class="h4 mb-4">Associa un cliente al suo primo impianto</p>
            <div class="row setup-content-2"">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
            session_start();
            include '../../connessione.php';
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $query_string = "SELECT * FROM clienti";
            $clienti = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
            ?>
            <div class="form-group md-form">

            <select id="SELEZIONA_CLIENTE" name="cliente_id_campagna" class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Cerca il nominativo dei tuoi clienti">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Nominativo cliente</option>
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clienti)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['cliente_id'] ;?>"><?php echo $row['nome'].'&nbsp;'. $row['cognome'] ;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <label>Nome Cliente</label>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            // Material Select Initialization
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mdb-select').material_select();
            });
            </script>
            </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
            session_start();
            include '../../connessione.php';
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $query_string = "SELECT * FROM store_locator WHERE store_locator.id NOT IN (SELECT impianto_id_campagna FROM campagne_cliente)";
            $impianti = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
            ?>
            <div class="form-group md-form">

            <select id="SELEZIONA_IMPIANTO"   name="impianto_id_campagna[]" class="ciao colorful-select dropdown-primary" multiple searchable="Cerca il CIM">
            <option value="" disabled selected>CIM</option>
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($impianti)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"><?php echo $row['cimasa'] ;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <label>Cim Impianto</label>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            // Material Select Initialization
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.ciao').material_select();
            });
            </script>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group md-form">
            </div>
            </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function SELEZIONA_FORM(){
    var e=document.getElementById("SELEZIONA_CLIENTE").value;//alert(e);
    if(e===""){
        alert("nothing selected");
        return false;
    }
        var o=document.getElementById("SELEZIONA_IMPIANTO").value;//alert(o);
    if(o===""){
        alert("nothing SELEZIONA_IMPIANTO");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I do?

Comment: What's the difference between **I miss selecting the second** and **I do not select anything in the second select**. Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: Are you saying that when you don't select anything from the second select, you get the alert for the first select?

Comment: @Barmar yes of course

Comment: I can't see any reason for it. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the function and single-stepping through it?

Comment: @Barmar nope, how can make this?

Comment: @Barmar maybe i have conflict for this reason? 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/mdb.min.js"></script>

Comment: I can't think of any way that those libraries could cause this. The browser has a fabulous debugger, learn to use it.

Comment: @Barmar i use console and i find this: Access to resource at 'https://sfmonitor.herokuapp.com/f?h=localhost:8888&v=stolen#' from origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @Barmar it s a virus? it's impossible....

Comment: That's a problem with a cross-origin AJAX request, I don't think it has anything to do with this.

Comment: @Barmar how to write my code with break ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the problem has something to do with the `material_select` plugin. I don't know what that is.